# Set page width dynamically in rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I have a problem regarding rdlc reports. I need 2 different reports whose contents are exactly same, they differ only in the number of columns. I want to make only one rdlc report for it. Then will hide some of the columns according to user input and will generate the report accordingly.

The problem is while exporting to PDF one report size is fine but the report with all columns breaks. Is this possible or I need to make 2 different rdlc reports?

Answer (score 0):

Make your reportbody's **ConsumeContainerWhitespace** is set to True.
I hope your using visibility property to hide columns.
The page might be breaking because the table width with all columns might be exceeding the Entire Page Width.

> Column width cannot be changed dynamically changed using Expression.
>   But if you are using tablix and the maximum number of columns is fixed
>   then you can create a workaround for it  else if the columns are
>   dynamic i.e if your using Matrix then you cannot change column width
>   dynamically based on number of columns.